# Scraping a website xml code daily to update a csv file in python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I know that many versions of this basic question have been asked but I can find nothing that really helps with this particular item.

https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Datasets/yield.xml

I need to scrape this site for the daily Treasury yields and write them with headers to a CSV file.

I need this to repeat each day so the CSV is always current.

I am working in python 3.6.3 with beautifulsoup4

So far I have been about to write the headers, and I can parse the xml in python, but I have been unable to write the headers and then the data to a CSV.

I tried this solution as a guide, and was able to get the headers to write.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-beautiful-soup-and-python-3

Then other posts here on stackexchange have helped me read the xml, but bridging the two, writing the xml headers and data to CSV and then updating it.

Here is the current code, such as it is.

```js
# Import libraries
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = csv.writer(open('treasury_yieldsV5.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(['Date', '1 Mo', '3 Mo', '6 Mo', '1 Yr', '2 Yr', '3 Yr', '5 Yr', '7 Yr', '10 Yr' ,'20 Yr' ,'30 Yr'])
infile = open("yield.xml","r")
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')
titles = soup.find_all('m:properties')
for title in titles:
    print(title.get_text())
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Just realized that code was from a prev version, the xml site is

Comment: _" I have been unable to write the headers and then the data to a CSV"_ -- if you don't explicitly tell us what is not working we cannot help you.  Show what you expect for output and what you actually got.  Also, the code you provided doesn't seem to actually attempt to do what you say you want.  Please post the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML into other XML, HTML, or even text files (CSV/TAB/JSON). With Python's `lxml` module, you can run XSLT 1.0 scripts eliminating any `for` loops. Otherwise, have Python call dedicating third-party [XSLT processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) like Saxon/Xalan; Linux/Mac's [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html); or Window's .NET [System.Xml.Xsl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx) via PowerShell.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="delim">,</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="quote">"</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/QR_BC_CM">
       <!-- HEADERS -->
       <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, 'Date', $quote, $delim, $quote, '1 Mo', $quote, $delim, $quote, '3 Mo', $quote, $delim,  
                                    $quote, '6 Mo', $quote, $delim, $quote, '1 Yr', $quote, $delim, $quote, '2 Yr', $quote, $delim,  
                                    $quote, '3 Yr', $quote, $delim, $quote, '5 Yr', $quote, $delim, $quote, '7 Yr', $quote, $delim,  
                                    $quote, '10 Yr', $quote, $delim, $quote, '20 Yr', $quote, $delim, $quote, '30 Yr', $quote)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="LIST_G_WEEK_OF_MONTH"/>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="LIST_G_WEEK_OF_MONTH|G_WEEK_OF_MONTH|LIST_G_NEW_DATE|G_NEW_DATE|LIST_G_BC_CAT">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="G_WEEK_OF_MONTH">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="LIST_G_NEW_DATE"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="G_NEW_DATE">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="LIST_G_BC_CAT"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="G_BC_CAT">
        <!-- DATA ROWS -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, ancestor::G_NEW_DATE/BID_CURVE_DATE, $quote, $delim,
                                     $quote, BC_1MONTH, $quote, $delim, $quote, BC_3MONTH, $quote, $delim,
                                     $quote, BC_6MONTH, $quote, $delim, $quote, BC_1YEAR, $quote, $delim,
                                     $quote, BC_2YEAR, $quote, $delim, $quote, BC_3YEAR, $quote, $delim,
                                     $quote, BC_5YEAR, $quote, $delim, $quote, BC_7YEAR, $quote, $delim,
                                     $quote, BC_10YEAR, $quote, $delim, $quote, BC_20YEAR, $quote, $delim,
                                     $quote, BC_30YEAR, $quote)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(reading directly from url, transform XML to CSV)*

```
import requests as rq
import lxml.etree as et

# RETRIEVE WEB CONTENT
data = rq.get("https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Datasets/yield.xml")

# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
doc = et.fromstring(data.text)
xsl = et.parse("TreasuryYields.xsl")

# TRANSFORM XML
transformer = et.XSLT(xsl)
result = transformer(doc)

# OUTPUT TO CONSOLE AND FILE
print(str(result))

with open("TreasuryYields.csv", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(result))
```

**Output** *(Thanksgiving being a U.S. federal holiday maintains no yields)*

```
"Date","1 Mo","3 Mo","6 Mo","1 Yr","2 Yr","3 Yr","5 Yr","7 Yr","10 Yr","20 Yr","30 Yr"
"01-NOV-17","1.06","1.18","1.3","1.46","1.61","1.74","2.01","2.22","2.37","2.63","2.85"
"02-NOV-17","1.02","1.17","1.29","1.46","1.61","1.73","2","2.21","2.35","2.61","2.83"
"03-NOV-17","1.02","1.18","1.31","1.49","1.63","1.74","1.99","2.19","2.34","2.59","2.82"
"06-NOV-17","1.03","1.19","1.3","1.5","1.61","1.73","1.99","2.17","2.32","2.58","2.8"
"07-NOV-17","1.05","1.22","1.33","1.49","1.63","1.75","1.99","2.17","2.32","2.56","2.77"
"08-NOV-17","1.05","1.23","1.35","1.53","1.65","1.77","2.01","2.19","2.32","2.57","2.79"
"09-NOV-17","1.07","1.24","1.36","1.53","1.63","1.75","2.01","2.2","2.33","2.59","2.81"
"10-NOV-17","1.06","1.23","1.37","1.54","1.67","1.79","2.06","2.27","2.4","2.67","2.88"
"13-NOV-17","1.07","1.24","1.37","1.55","1.7","1.82","2.08","2.27","2.4","2.67","2.87"
"14-NOV-17","1.06","1.26","1.4","1.55","1.68","1.81","2.06","2.26","2.38","2.64","2.84"
"15-NOV-17","1.08","1.25","1.39","1.55","1.68","1.79","2.04","2.21","2.33","2.58","2.77"
"16-NOV-17","1.08","1.27","1.42","1.59","1.72","1.83","2.07","2.25","2.37","2.62","2.81"
"17-NOV-17","1.08","1.29","1.42","1.6","1.73","1.83","2.06","2.23","2.35","2.59","2.78"
"20-NOV-17","1.09","1.3","1.46","1.62","1.77","1.86","2.09","2.26","2.37","2.6","2.78"
"21-NOV-17","1.15","1.3","1.45","1.62","1.77","1.88","2.11","2.27","2.36","2.58","2.76"
"22-NOV-17","1.16","1.29","1.45","1.61","1.74","1.84","2.05","2.22","2.32","2.57","2.75"
"23-NOV-17","","","","","","","","","","",""
"24-NOV-17","1.14","1.29","1.45","1.61","1.75","1.85","2.07","2.23","2.34","2.58","2.76"
```